# Web optimizer .net core

Tags: jquery-ui, asp.net-core-mvc, bundling-and-minification, kendo-asp.net-core, weboptimizer

Upgrading .net 4.8 mvc app to .net 6. I am keeping the static content in the same folders as in the previous web app project and using the web optimizer to minify and bundle.

I am seeing lot of console errors and the UI is not loading for the app

[image]

Layout cshtml
[image]

Script and Content folder

[image]

[image]

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: It is a part of big app so I am unable to make that happen quickly. I am trying to work on the same it might take some time as I am new, but if anyone has any suggestions please do let me know

Answer (score 0):

It may help if you could show how you configured in program.cs

I tried as the [document](https://github.com/ligershark/WebOptimizer) :

In program.cs:

```
builder.Services.AddWebOptimizer(x =>x.AddJavaScriptBundle("/js/bundle.js", "js/chat/*.js"));
```

call

```
app.UseWebOptimizer();
```

before:

```
app.UseStaticFiles();
```

in chat.js:

```
console.log("chat");
```

in hellow.js:

```
console.log("hellow");
```

And my project:

[image]

in my View,I called:

```
<script src="/js/bundle.js"></script>
```

The result:

[image]

other [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/client-side/bundling-and-minification?view=aspnetcore-6.0) may help:

**Update:**

I tried to add two floders under the directory of the project as your comment and tried as below to fix the 404 error:

```
var provider1 = new Microsoft.Extensions.FileProviders.PhysicalFileProvider(Path.Combine(builder.Environment.ContentRootPath, "Script1"));
    var provider2 = new Microsoft.Extensions.FileProviders.PhysicalFileProvider(Path.Combine(builder.Environment.ContentRootPath, "Script2"));
builder.Services.AddWebOptimizer
(x =>
 {    
x.AddJavaScriptBundle("/bundle1.js","/chat/*.js").UseFileProvider(provider1); 
   x.AddJavaScriptBundle("/bundle2.js","/comment/*.js").UseFileProvider(provider2);
});
```

My project:

[image]

Comment: Hi Ruikai Feng, Thank you so much for your response. I did create a small app when trying weboptimizer myself and did refer the js and css as shown in my snapshot For e.g. <script src="~/js/scripts" asp-append-version="true"></script> and <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/css/css" asp-append-version=true />

Comment: In program cs I do have builder.Services.AddWebOptimizer(pipeline => 
{
 pipeline.AddCssBundle("/css/css", "Content/file1.css","Content/Level/file2.css").UseContentRoot();
 var provider = new Microsoft.Extensions.FileProviders.PhysicalFileProvider(Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(),"Scripts"));
 pipeline.AddJavaScriptBundle("/js/Scripts","Lvlchk/*.js").UseFileProvider(provider);
});
and UseWebOptimizer(); before UseStaticFiles call

Comment: I have Content folder under which I have file 1 css and Level folder which has file2 css and have a Scripts folder that has one site.js under a folder Lvlchk. Since all this worked in my sample app this is why I implemented similarly in the original app which is giving me those issues shown in the main question snap

Comment: I tried to move the js files into  two different floders  under the directory of the project (not wwwroot)and reproduced the 404 error you've got, I defined two  providers instead of one with .UseContentRoot() and one with .UseFileProvider(provider) and solved the 404 error

Comment: The 403 error seems have no relationship with WebOptimizer

Comment: In my sample app it does resolve but I do not think it will work for me to create multiple provider path every time and folders. I am switching to bundleconfig (Bundling and Minification extension in VS)

Comment: it may help if you could upload the minimal codes that could reproduce the error to github